# Data exchange between Activities, Asynctasks and Services

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

Regarding the problematic stated below I have come to a point where I need to make a decision on whether to:

- Start a Service once that has an AlarmManager inside which then starts the query every 10 minutes. This Service will only be stopped if the user sets an "Onn-Off" Switch to "Off".
- Use an AlarmManager to start an IntentService every 10 Minutes. This Service will then only be started when needed and closed afterwards

Which of these ways is better when it comes to:
- Ability to exchange data received by the Service (Or Intenservice) with other activities/services
- Battery usage
- Overall "good coding habits" ?

Thanks!

Original Question:

I am a pretty new Android Developer and have come across a situation that I do not know how to solve. I have already spent several days searching for a solution but could not find one.

While trying to develop my first app idea I have started playing around with receiving and parsing data from the internet. What I have achieved so far is generating a query that receives JSON data via an API and parses this JSON. All of which is done inside an AsyncTask. The received data is then shown on the screen.

However, for the purpose of my app idea, I need this to be done in the background. What I have thought of is:

- Starting a Service that pretty much has the same logic as my Asynctask. Managed by an AlarmManager, this service then requests, receives and parses the data in a specific time interval.

Now the tricky part begins:
The data that I receive (let's say every 10 minutes) shall be used to change an alarm clock. So, as a simple example, let's say the user can set his alarm clock to 08:00 in the morning. The application then checks the current temperature every 10 minutes and changes the alarm clock time to 07:45 if the temperature is below 0° celcius because the user has to wake up earlier to clear the ice off his car.
Also, when "waking up" the application, the current (or rather the latest received) tempereture shall be shown in the UI.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I am having some issues regarding passing/receiving data from AsyncTasks/Services to/from Activities.

My first approach would be to start a single service from the MainActivity, passing some data to the Service (like the initial time the alarm shall start and the current location of the user). The Service then has two seperate AlarmManagers. One of which is set to perform the actual alarm (waking up the user in the morning) and the other manages the time interval of getting the data from the internet.

My questions:
- Does my train of thought make any sense at all so far?
- What is the best way to pass and receive data to/from a service? My best guess would be to use intents to pass and a broadcastreceiver to receive data from the service. would this make sense in this specific situation?

I fear that it is not welcomed to post questions without putting in any effort of your own before. Although I did not add any actual source code, I hope you can see that I have dealt with these questions for quite a while now but could not really start coding before I know the structure of the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to start an `IntentService` as often as necessary (in your example, it should be sufficient to start checking the temperature about two hours before the user plans to get up and maybe again after one hour and finally half an hour before the normal wakeup time. More often only in case of extreme weather conditions.

It's not necessary to check the temperature exactly at 03:33 a.m. so use 
`setInexactRepeating()`, this will be easier on the battery.

See also [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Write the results to `SharedPreferences` and have one `IntentService` check 15 minutes before normal wakeup time if the user should get up right then. Cancel the normal wakeup alarm in this case. Communicating via `SharedPreferences` (think of a mailbox) and local (!) Broadcasts is a good idea - cheap and secure :)